# Is it possible to ride ordinary trains in Egypt as foreigners?

Tags: trains, egypt

We are planning to take the train from Aswan to Luxor in the morning to continue on by bus to the Red Sea in the afternoon.

There is a deluxe train at 7:30am, but we won't be able to make it due to our ferry constraints. There is also an ordinary train at 9:30 am. Even third class tickets are not available to be purchased in advance for this train.

Is it possible for two German tourists to take such train?

Comment: Any reason why you think you wouldn't be allowed to ?

Comment: Have you checked other departures? I think your departure is sold out 

Comment: From memory from 3 years ago, you can buy tickets but at the station they usually try to sell you tickets for tourists train rather than local trains. I took the train there and a friend of mine had to bargain in Arabic, but perhaps things have changed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We went to the station this morning; at the ticket window they told us to buy tickets on the train. But on the platform the police officers and railway staff informed us that we can not board the train. Foreigners are not allowed to ride on ordinary trains. Telling them we need to get a connection in Luxor didn't help.

My girlfriend speaks nearly perfect Egyptian Arabic, so communication was no problem. She had to take the case to the commander in charge of the station police and had to get very loud to get an exemption for us. We were then escorted to the train and seated in the special section reserved for police officers.

The ride was an interesting but loud and very smelly experience.

So at a major station is not possible to get on the train without speaking good Arabic and standing your ground.

At a small station without police you may be able to board and after the train is moving they won't kick you out at the next station.

They claimed something about missing insurance for the train class as the reason for not allowing foreigners.

I would not recommend the risk; try taking a deluxe train, it is not that much more expensive.

Comment: If you had asked further in advance I would have pointed to https://www.seat61.com/Egypt.htm#Tourist%20travel%20restrictions which has summaries of travellers' experiences. They seem more positive than yours but not for the exact same train.

Comment: @mdewey I know the sest61 Egypt page very well. The restrictions mentioned there are for the deluxe daytime train. A completely different thing. Thank you anyway.